# Running a macro in specific computer if the same Outlook session is open on two computers

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two computers, one handling automated reports and sending emails, and one where I do my work. Both have Outlook open with my session.

Sometimes office updates, or an external app crashes and my automated reports are done.

I found code which will help restarting everything by receiving an email with a certain subject.

Will Outlook run the macro on the report computer or my working computer?

Can I force it to run on the report computer?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_NewMail()

    Dim exApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

    Set Msg = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.GetLast
    If Msg.Subject = "Reinicia todo" Then
        CerrarProcesos
        Set wb = exApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Alertas Renfe.xlsb")
        exApp.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub


Sub CerrarProcesos()

    Dim oServ As Object
    Dim cProc As Variant
    Dim oProc As Object

    Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

    For Each oProc In cProc 'Case Sensitive
        If oProc.Name Like "Acs*.exe" Or oProc.Name Like "acs*.exe" Or oProc.Name Like "ACS*.exe" Or oProc.Name Like "EXCEL*" Then
          oProc.Terminate
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The common sense would suggest that you need this on your report computer... as you can send the email to it to "Reinicia todo".

Comment: That's what I did, outlook won't share the code to the other computer then?